# Is there are more efficient way in writing this function?

Tags: jquery

Is there are more efficient way in writing this function?

```
$('input').change(function() {

    if($("#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5").is(":checked")){

    // do something
    }

    else if($("#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5").is(":not(:checked)")){

    // do something

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove `if($("#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5").is(":not(:checked)"))` from the `else` test.

Comment: They are radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The `else if` is not needed, just an `if/else` would do it:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    if($("#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5").is(":checked")){
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You could also add a class to your elements in order to make the selector shorter:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    if($(".radios").is(":checked")){
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Another approach, if both your `if/else` blocks have many lines of code, you can move them to named functions and use a ternary operator:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    return $("#m1, #m2, #m3, #m4, #m5").is(":checked") ? funcForChecked() : funcForUnchecked();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Event Listeners you have the `this` object representing the element which triggered the event, so you can write:

```
$('input').change(function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        // do something

       return;
    }

    // do something        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing all those  I.D's you could mark them with a Class i.e "checkbox" and use the following

```
if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){ blah blah } ;
```

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hyopdt3v/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have something like

```
<input id="m1" type="radio" name="groupName" />
...
<input id="m5" type="radio" name="groupName" />
```

In that case you could wrap the group into a div with its own id:

```
<div id="m15">
</div>
```

and bind the change event to that:

```
$('#m15').change(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input').is(":checked")) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Or you can be more specific using classes:

```
<div id="m15">
    ...
    <input id="m1" class="m15" />
</div>

$('#m15').change(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input.m15').is(":checked")) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Since they are radio buttons, either none is checked, or only one is checked.

For the same reason this would work:

```
$('#m15 input.m15').change(function() {
    // Triggered the first time - and all subsequent times
});
```

Your current code is bound to **all** `input` elements, which means it will trigger even if one changes some other control; it seems to me that this is undesirable behaviour.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4v85v2y/) for both codes.